# Add new multiple Index, can i remove single index?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have database postgresql, where is table.

```
CREATE TABLE film_ratings
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  film_id integer NOT NULL,
  user_id integer NOT NULL,
  rating smallint NOT NULL,
  inserted_datetime timestamp without time zone DEFAULT date_trunc('second'::text, now()),
  updated_datetime timestamp without time zone DEFAULT date_trunc('second'::text, now()),
  CONSTRAINT film_ratings_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT film_ratings_film_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (film_id)
      REFERENCES pw_filmy (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE RESTRICT ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT film_ratings_user_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (user_id)
      REFERENCES pw_uzivatele (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE RESTRICT ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT film_ratings_film_id_user_id_ukey UNIQUE (film_id, user_id)
);

CREATE INDEX film_ratings_inserted_datetime_index ON film_ratings (inserted_datetime DESC);
CREATE INDEX film_ratings_user_id_inserted_datetime_index ON film_ratings (user_id, inserted_datetime DESC);
-- two single indexies
CREATE INDEX film_ratings_film_index ON film_ratings (film_id);
CREATE INDEX film_ratings_user_index ON film_ratings (user_id);
```

And my question is, can I remove two last indexes (**film_ratings_film_index** and **film_ratings_user_index**)? Where are contains in multiple indexes like is unique **film_ratings_film_id_user_id_ukey** and **film_ratings_user_id_inserted_datetime_index**.

Table has more than 70 millions rows.

Comment: Do your queries use one of these indexes? If not, just drop them. Check pg_stat_user_indexes to get information about your indexes. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/monitoring-stats.html#MONITORING-STATS-VIEWS

Answer (score 0):

your index is primarily picked on the columns in the where clause, if you have film_id or user_id and one of the sole columns in the where clause of your frequently used sql, you can keep it.